# Pinia store: Initial data fetching on store creation

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

In my Vue app I am using several Pinia stores. For most of them, I need to initialize the state with data from a server, i.e. I need to wait for a server response. I'm trying to do this with [Setup style stores](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/#Setup-Stores).

I don't want to explicity call an `initialize` function somewhere else in the code. So currently, if I access the state, the store checks if it is initialized and then - if necessary - gets the data from the server.

This looks something like this:

**myStore.js**

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import { ref, computed } from "vue";
import myApi from "server";


export const myStore = defineStore("myStore", () => {
  const data = ref();
  const isInitialized = ref(false);

  // Get data from server and set state to initialized. Only get data if the store is not yet initialized.
  async function fetchData() {
    if (!isInitialized.value) {
      const res = await myApi.fetchData();
      data.value = res.data;
      isInitialized.value = true;
    }
  }

  // Getter for accessing data. First fetch data from server if necessary.
  const getData = computed(() => {
    fetchData();
    return data;
  });

  return { getData };
});
```

Now this isn't nice, since `computed` should be side-effect free and I don't want to repeat this for all the other getters in this store.

Is there something similar like lifecycle hooks for Pinia stores? Then I could simply directly get the data, as soon as the store is created. If this isn't possible, what would be a better pattern to achieve the same result?

Comment: This is part of the `Setup style` for Pinia. refs represent state and computed represent getters.

Comment: Ah right, I was unfamiliar. I've only used the Option store style before.

Comment: Have you ever had the same use case? How do you solve it with an Option store?

Comment: There are no lifecycle hooks in pinia. I think you can build a better solution with a pinia plugin. There are a lot of samples on the pinia website maybe you can figure it out by yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I am trying out some things, but I can't find out how the plugin can change the actual `data` state in `myStore`. I also can't think of a solution for state name to be dynamic, depending on the store. For example, in another store, the state that has to be initialized might be called `foo` instead of `data`. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store initialization is synchronous, not to mention that there would be race conditions when uninitialized data is accessed without a promise to await.

There needs to be explicit initialization method:

```
async function initialize() {
  await myApi.fetchData();
}
```

Which should be called as early as needed, e.g. in root component with suspense, or with top-level await:

```
await myStore.initialize()
```

Another case for initialization method is that store initialization can be parametrized, this makes the usage more flexible and improves testability.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The issue I have with explicitly calling an initialize function from outside the store is that I have several nested stores and the user's path is not defined. Because of that, I would either have to initialize a store in more than one place in the code, or I would have to initialize all stores at top level, which I want to avoid.

Comment: I generally do this at top level, probably not the app but a specific module that depends on myStore, probably can be optimized for your case. Not doing this results in viral undetermined state in linked stores and requires to add `myStore.initialized` condition in multiple places, this can quickly become messy in real-world scenario. You can get away with this with computeds but when a method depends on uninitialized data, you're supposed to call it again in a watcher. The case isn't really unique to pinia and vue, would be roughly the same with any kinds of services in any framework

Comment: I ended up doing a combination of your suggestion and my solution. I use a composable, to which I pass the init function for the respective store. Then, whenever I import the store, I call this init function. The function simply does nothing, if the store was already initialized.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve the problem with a composable. Here is the code.

#### myStore.js

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import { ref, computed } from "vue";
import myApi from "server";
import { useInitializeStore } from "composables/useInitializeStore";


export const myStore = defineStore("myStore", () => {
  const data = ref();

  // Get data from server and set state to initialized.
  // Set loading state while data is not yet available.
  const { initialized, loading } = useInitializeStore(async () => {
    const res = await myApi.fetchData();
    data.value = res.data;
  });

  // Getter for accessing data.
  const getData = computed(() => {
    return data;
  });

  return { getData, initialized, loading };
});
```

#### useInitializeStore.js

```
import { ref } from "vue";

export function useInitializeStore(apiCall) {
  const initialized = ref(false);
  const loading = ref(false);

  (async function () {
    loading.value = true;
    await apiCall();
    initialized.value = true;
    loading.value = false;
  })();

  return { initialized, loading };
}
```

This way I am able to define the actual API call in each store. By using an IIFE in the composable, the API call will be handled directly when calling `useInitializeStore` in the store.

Also, I have added the `initialized` and the `loading` state, so I can appropriately react to the current state of the API request.

Comment: `if (!initialized.value)` is not necessary as the condition is always true

Comment: You are right. I was just being paranoid with that one. I edited the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found a good solution to this by putting the `async` store initialization inside a separate `<Suspense>` component. This way, we can organize all store creations/initializations in one convenient place.

My stores need to be created and initialized after a successful login (`AWS Amplify`) so that they can access sensitive information with the credentials.

In `main.ts` we will `app.use(pinia)` as normal:

```js
// main.ts

...
import { createPinia } from "pinia";

const app = createApp(App);
app.use(createPinia());

app.mount("#app");
```

In `App.vue` is where the trick comes in. In the `AUTH ZONE` we are going to put a `StoreInit` component inside a `Suspense` in order to allow us to use an `async` initialization for our stores. The router will be used to display our actual content.

```js
// App.vue

<script setup lang="ts">
import StoreInit from "./StoreInit.vue";
</script>

<template>
   <authenticator>
      ...
      // AUTH ZONE
      ...
     <Suspense>
       <StoreInit />
     </Suspense>
     <router-view :user="user" />
      ...
      // AUTH ZONE
      ...
   </authenticator>
</template>
```

In `StoreInit.vue` we will initialize the stores. But first, here's a sample `auth-store` used to get credentials:

```js
// auth-store.ts

import { ref } from "vue";
import { fetchAuthSession, getCurrentUser } from "aws-amplify/auth";
import type { AuthTokens } from "aws-amplify/auth";
import { defineStore } from "pinia";

export const useAuthStore = defineStore("userAuth", () => {
  const tokens = ref();
  const credentials = ref();
  const userName = ref();

  async function initStore(): Promise<void> {
    const authSession = await fetchAuthSession();
    const userAttributes = await getCurrentUser();
    userName.value = userAttributes.username;
    credentials.value = authSession.credentials;
    tokens.value = authSession.tokens as AuthTokens;
  }

  return { initStore, credentials, tokens, userName };
});
```

Now to create and initialize this store after a login, let's put it in `StoreInit.vue`:

```js
// StoreInit.vue

// Need this empty template just to keep vue from complaining
<template></template>

<script setup lang="ts">
// Stores to init
import { useAuthStore } from "@/stores/auth-store";

const authStore = useAuthStore();
await authStore.initStore();
</script>
```

If you need some way to check initialization in your stores, you can use another method in your store:

```js
  async function _checkInit() {
    // Just making sure the store is initialized
    if (tokens.value == null) {
      await initStore();
    }
  }
```

Now you can just throw `await _checkInit()` in front of any other store method that depends on your values being properly initialized.