# Vue.js 3 and Pinia store filled in async by API

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, pinia, vue-sfc

I'm creating an application in Vue.js 3 + Pinia. I created an action that call - async function with await on axios call - an API to fill the whole store for a page, but don't work.

Are there any method to await the full update of the store? The issue at the moment is that getters return nothing when loading the page. I'm also following the official documentation for deconstruct the getters and I launch the action call in "wrapped" in "onBeforeMount".

**More detail about the what is the workflow**:

In the main page I call the API to fetch in the store all the data (also the data for the Vue-Components), the function is wrapped with "onBeforeMount". The data that is **not** related to a Vue-Component is printed to the main page.

In the component I call the storage (useStore()) and I use "storeToRefs" to deconstruct the getter and the result is undefined.

**A possible solution:**
This issue occurred because I want to avoid to use props to Vue-Components also because I have nested components sometimes.

Comment: This addresses exactly this problem, https://stackoverflow.com/a/77427964/3731501 . You need to await for the initialization to be completed before mounting the app. You can do this with suspense in vue 3

Comment: Do I have to apply <Suspense>...</Suspense> to whole template of the page while is it loading? Also for each Component that use the store?

Comment: No, it's unnecessary to have more than one <suspense>, but it should be one level higher, e.g. do await store.init() in Page async setup, and have <suspense> in root comp