# How to fetch data when store is initialized?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex, nuxtjs3, pinia

I have a simple store that gets its data by fetch:

```js
export const useCatStore = defineStore('cats', {
  state: () => ({
    cats: [],
    pending: true,
    error: undefined,
  }),
  actions: {
    async update() {
      this.pending = true;

      try {
        this.cats = await $fetch<Cat[]>('/api/cats');
      } catch (error) {
        this.error = error;
      }

      this.pending = false;
    },
  },
});
```

But how can I get `update()` called as soon as the store is used? Right now I need to call `update()` from a component:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
const store = useCatStore();

onBeforeMount(() => {
  store.update();
});
</script>

<template>
   <template v-if="store.pending">
      Loading...
   </tempalte>

   <template v-if="store.error && !store.pending">
      Error: {{store.error}}
   </tempalte>

   <template v-if="store.cats">
      {{store.cats}}
   </tempalte>
</template>
```

But this has multiple drawbacks:

- Some component must be responsible for initially calling the update() function
- When multiple of this components are on one page the fetch is called multiple times
- When this component is not used the store data is empty but I might need it in another (different) component

Is there any possibility to let the `update()` action be called automatically when the store is initialized?

Comment: It's a bad practice to lose the control over update calls, this will cause more harm than good. You'll have to listen for store.pending in all derived data, which results in spaghetti code. Generally you can use suspense to block rendering of the whole app or its part that depends on async action, which also works good with ssr. This is relevant, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77427537/pinia-store-initial-data-fetching-on-store-creation/77427964#77427964